# Opening Trace in SQL Server Profiler Using Disk Space

Tags: sql-server-2005, disk-space-utilization, sql-server

I've got a server set up with a smaller c: drive for applications and a huge d: for storage.  I've recently run a SQL Server trace using SQL Server Profiler and stored the results to file on the d: drive.  When attempting to open the results though I am running out of free space on the c: drive before it can finish opening so that I can actually do anything with it.

Is there any way I can convince SQL Server Profiler to create its temporary files, or whatever it thinks it needs all that disk space for, on d: where there's plenty of room?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem when replaying a trace. If you don't replay the results to screen then the temp files don't grow.

Or you can change the location of where the temp files are put by changing the tmp and temp user windows variables. (right click my computer, click properties, click advanced tab, click on Environment variables).

Answer (score 0):

> When attempting to open the results
>   though I am running out of free space
>   on the c: drive before it can finish
>   opening so that I can actually do
>   anything with it.

Move the trace file off the server, or try opening from your client using a share/urn.

Answer (score 0):

Never run SQL Server Profiler on Production Servers. Instead use Server Side Traces. I had blogged about this [here](http://www.sqldbadiaries.com/2010/08/21/sql-server-proilfer-and-the-c-drive-space-issue/)